# What is the name of this bush/shrub?

Tags: shrubs

What is the name of this plant? For how long does it produce flowers like that?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shrub is a hydrangea, specifically a cultivar of *Hydrangea paniculata*. Given its size and age, it may be the cultivar Pee Gee ([Hydrangea paniculata 'Grandiflora'](https://plants.ces.ncsu.edu/plants/hydrangea-paniculata-grandiflora/)), which is a fairly old one. This type of hydrangea produces flowers for about a month to six weeks; in many cultivars, the flowers turn pink (or even a dark rose) as they age, after which they slowly "tan out" as they dry. Many gardeners like the look of the dried flowers and leave them on the shrub for winter interest, cutting them off only in early spring.

Comment: Are you saying these are old ants and it will take a long time for them to grow that big?

Comment: Sorry for the mis-understanding! When I said the cultivar is old, I meant that it had been released into the horticultural trade a rather long time ago (IIRC, Pee Gee was the first commonly available large-flowered H. paniculata cultivar). The plant in the photo is possibly no more than five years old, depending on soil fertility and water availability. I own a different H. paniculata cultivar that this year has four-five feet of new growth and, in only three years, is already eight feet tall.